# Get month and year of javascript Date in my locale

Tags: javascript, date

**My code**

```
nouveautes.forEach(function(nouveaute) {
  console.log(nouveaute.createdAt.toLocaleString());
  nouveaute.createdAt = nouveaute.createdAt.toLocaleString();
  console.log(nouveaute.createdAt.getMonth());
  nouveaute.createdAt = nouveaute.createdAt.getMonth() + " " + nouveaute.createdAt.getYear();
  console.log(nouveaute.createdAt);
});
```

**Output with 2 objects in array**

```
2017-11-12 16:15:03
10
2017-11-12T15:15:03.000Z

2017-11-10 11:09:10
10
2017-11-10T10:09:10.000Z
```

I'd like to have :

In french :

```
// => Novembre 2017
```

Or if it's too difficult, in english :

```
// => November 2017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used moment.js library!

```
moment.lang('fr');
moment().format('MMMM YYYY');
```

https://momentjs.com/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JRvJ9aMLzc

Comment: It require additional library, but it gives flexibility in dealing with dates!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toLocaleString)

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

var options = { year: "numeric", month: "long"};
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", options));
// -> Novembre 2017
```

Comment: This work without any aditionnal librairy :)